# Set highstock chart navigator max range by default

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a set of pulled data which I don't know the start date and the end date. on page load, i want the highstock chart to set the navigator to range from the start date through the end date, like its zoomed out all the way, similar to clicking the "All" button in the rangeSelector. Unfortunately, the mockup requires that we remove the range selector and the date input fields so we're only left with the navigator. How do I do that?

The current range of the navigator seems to be on the most recent year only but I don't want that. Looked through lots of forums but can't find any solution. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to call [setExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes) on xAxis, with defined min/max. These values can be extracted from our source data (first and last element).